# Hive - How do I get last months of data from Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How do I get last 2 months of data from Hive?

Here is my attempt:

```
select (date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
     2 - month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
    ));
```

This results in 2015-05-30. The results should be like: if Today is '2015-06-03', then the result of last two months should be like: '2015-04-01'. Notice that I put the first day of the month for the results. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Extra Notes:

In SQL is it pretty easy to get:

```
 select * from date_field >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Why would two months ago be 2015-04-01 and not 2015-04-03?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567896/hive-function-add-month-to-date

Answer (score 0):

date_add adds days, not months. The below line evaluates to `-4`

```
2 - month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

So you are basically subtracting 4 days from '2015-06-03', which is why you get the result '2015-05-30'.

As far as I know, there is no direct way to subtract months in Hive. Solutions you could consider:

1. Subtract 60 days, but that won't give you accurate results.
2. Write a custom UDF to return the date 2 months ago.
3. Calculate the date in a script, and pass it to hive.