# How to subtract months from date in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, bigdata

I am looking for a method that helps me subtract months from a date in HIVE

I have a date `2015-02-01`. Now i need to subtract 2 months from this date so that result should be `2014-12-01`.

Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: Reading the [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
 select add_months('2015-02-01',-2);
```

if you need to go back to first day of the resulting month:

```
 select add_months(trunc('2015-02-01','MM'),-2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try add_months date function and pass -2 as months. Internally add_months uses Java Calendar.add method, which supports adding or subtracting (by passing negative integer).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 1):

--in Hive if the date format is in YYYY-MM-DD format, it becomes really easy to use difference in terms on month and year

from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(2015-02-01,'yyyy-mm-dd')-2*30*24*60*60, 'yyyy-MM-dd');